Installed docker desktop on VMware machine. How to get VMware back working?
I do use VMWare Workstation on my machine and I wanted to try something with docker so I installed docker desktop on my windows machine with the recommended settings (WSL2).
After that I noticed that I can't use my VMs anymore. They just instant bluescreen with the error message "unsupported processor" when I start them.
I have read that docker + vmware on the same machine doesn't work out of the box.
Right now I just want to fix VMware Workstation. I have uninstalled docker and restarted my machine but the VMs still instant bluescreen on startup. There is also a message that states "You are running this virtual machine with side channel mitigations enabled" that was never displayed before.
How can I fix this?

My research suggests updating VMWare Workstation to the current version is the solution to this problem

Update: I uninstalled WSL via "windows features" and I have read that setting the core count to 1 will allow the VM to boot back up and that did actually work. So right now the only problems seems that the core count is limited to 1 on the specific VM I tryed to start while Docker was installed and that "channel mitigation" message on VM startup even I made sure that I dont have hyperV installed. @Ramhound Do you mean the latest v17 version? I am currently on v16 and I don't know if I can upgrade with my license.

Update: New installed VMs also instant bluescreen while windows installation with the same "unsupported processor" message...

VMWare Workstation is free as in air….has been for half a year and today it’s completely free.

I did those steps to fully revert the docker installation and allow VMware to work back again.

Uninstall Docker Desktop
Go to "Turn Windows Features on or Off" and uncheck "Windows subsystem for Linux" and "Virtual Machine Platform"
Restart PC

After that everything was working again. The problem might be that "Virtualization based securtiy" service was running and doing those steps will stop it. You can see if the service is running near the bottom inside "system information" from windows.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
